# How can I find the text show in the screen when linux boot? That's not the same as dmesg shows

Tags: linux, boot, dmesg

When gnu/linux boot message shows, that's not the same as `dmesg` shows. How can I find it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only output from the kernel itself will be in dmesg.

The other output is from the init process and the services it starts.  There are a number of different implementations of `init` commonly used on GNU/Linux (some of which aren't called "init") and their behavior may differ, and be configurable, in this context, but in my experience, they do not by default log everything they print to the screen.  Further, they don't redirect the output of the services they start -- anything those print to standard out or standard error will just end up on the screen.  It is up to the individual services what they do WRT to syslog<sup>1</sup> and output streams.  Most of them should make good use of syslog, but what they report there may not be the same as what they report to stdout/stderr at start-up.  Usually there will be a lot more in syslog than on the screen.

The three most common init implementations used on GNU/Linux, if you are interested in looking into specifics, are:

- [SysV init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SysV-style) (Debian, Gentoo, others): Originally, this was the only init system used by major linux distributions; technically SysV is a specification, the actual implementation used on linux was/is a GNU project.
- [Systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) (Fedora, Arch): Developed by Redhat.
- [Upstart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart) (Ubuntu): Developed by Canonical.

---

<sup>1</sup> If syslog isn't started yet, or the filesystem containing the logs isn't mounted read-write yet, messages might be discarded, which is why you can have a failed boot with no record in the logs -- the boot failed before logging is possible, but there is still output to the console.

Answer (score 0):

"Only output from the kernel itself will be in dmesg."

Indeed, thanks for 'just saying it'. However, what is the point of displaying a msg. to the screen if it scrolls past so fast that you can't see it, and can't (it seems) retrieve it? Many times I've seen some error msg. but it disappears so fast that I can't read it, and it's not in 'dmesg' either. I'd far rather that *everything* currently sent to the screen could somehow be captured in a log where it could be studied.

Comment: Good to have your response! However, it does not in any way answer the question concerned.

Comment: No it doesn't, but it does let me blow off some steam ;-) I trust it will be removed by the moderators. However, I'm trying to modify an init script to provide full logging. So far it's promising.